# Cannot access JavaScript object properties parsed from JSON

Tags: reactjs, fetch, javascript-objects, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to access an object's property with bracket & dot notation. But for some reason it's saying the object is not defined.

Below is the react code:

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});

  const fetchCovidData = () => {
    fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/country/south-africa")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchCovidData();
  }, []);

  return <h1>{data[0].City}</h1>;
};

export default App;
```

When I `console.log(data[0])` it prints out an object with the City attribute, but when I try to access it with the dot notation, it says `data[0]` is not defined. Is what I stored in the data state not an array of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the flow:

1. Your initial state of `data` is `{}`
2. When your component mounted, it will call the effect to fetch data.
3. Mean while, the component still renders what it've got. `<h1>{data[0].City}</h1>;` This line will get the `data[0]` which is `undefined`, an then try to access property `City` from that `undefined` object which eventually cause an error.
4. When your data is fetched, it will set the state of `data`, only then the `data` has content and `data[0].City` is valid

My suggestions are:

1. Make use of the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `return <h1>{data?.[0]?.City || "Loading..."}</h1>`
2. If your `data` will be an array of object, its initial state should be an empty array `[]`

[Demo code](https://codepen.io/dong-nhan/pen/OJNPqpX)

Comment: Nice. But now the h1 will only display Loading though. How do I get it to rerender? Do I use a useCallback hook to watch for data's state value?

Comment: When your data arrived, it will call `setData` and set the state correctly. Double check on the response data if it is in the correct structure.

Comment: @EddieLam oh sorry, we should only fetch it once. I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` method is an async method so you need to do something like this:

```
const fetchCovidData = async () => {
   await fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/country/south-africa")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => setData(result));
};
```

So it can wait for the fetchCovidData method to be processed.

Comment: I think the return line for the h1 tag didn't wait for the fetch function to complete, so was trying to access the City attribute of an empty object.