# Cannot reach "title" property in an Object which has this property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jsonplaceholder

When I try access "title" and "body" on "post" object it says that "Cannot find name 'title'."
I tried everything that I found here on stackoverflow, my code seems to be the same as the other ones, but I cannot figure out why it still not working.
I would appreciate if someone could find the problem and explain to a totally beginner.
Thank you! :)

```
const PostDetail = () => {
const { id } = useParams();

const [post, setPost] = useState({});

const getPost = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
            `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`
        );

        setPost(data);
        console.log(data);
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    getPost();
}, []);

return (
    <>
        <Header />
        <Navigator />
        <div className="App">
            <h3>Post details: {id}</h3>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>{body}</p>
        </div>
        <Footer />
    </>
);
```

};

export default PostDetail;

The error:

```
ERROR in src/pages/PostDetail.tsx:38:9
```

TS2304: Cannot find name 'title'.
36 |                        
37 |

#### Post details: {id}

> 38 |
>
> {title}
>
> /// Cannot find name 'title'.
> |                                    ^^^^^
> 39 |
>
> {body}
>
> /// Cannot find name 'body'.
> 40 |                        
> 41 |

ERROR in src/pages/PostDetail.tsx:39:9
TS2304: Cannot find name 'body'.
37 |

#### Post details: {id}

38 |

{title}

/// Cannot find name 'title'.

> 39 |
>
> {body}
>
> /// Cannot find name 'body'.
> |                                    ^^^^
> 40 |                        
> 41 |                        
> 42 |                </>

Comment: When the page first loads, before the call is complete, there is no `title` property on the object you initialize state to (`{}`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot access JavaScript object properties parsed from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311364/cannot-access-javascript-object-properties-parsed-from-json)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, it didn't work with optional chaining, but I understand your explanation so I set empty strings like initial values for "post" and now it's working. But I think it's not a good solution, only a temporary one :) Thank you very much for your explanation :)   

const [post, setPost] = useState({title: "", body: ""});

Answer (score -1):

I don't see it as a variable you save data on.
maybe you need to access it from the post object?
I say it because I see only Post state and no title state.

**Update**
I mean you save data in post
but title and body cant know that you need to write `post.title`
because title is just a variable he can't know what post child until you state so

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand. I thought that I saved data with setPost(data) to the "post" variable. If I console.log "data" I receive the object, but I cannot reach properties on it:
`Object { userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", body: "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto" }`

Comment: @Heidi see my update

Comment: sorry, but I still don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. I already did this before, but I received "Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'." error.

Comment: @Heidi
so do this `post?.title`
read about Optional chaining (?.)